# sed command in build script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, build-process

I'm new to sed command. I was reading the build script for some source code and I found this for loop in it.

```
for x in '*.la'    
do    
sed -i -e 's|^\(libdir=.\).*\(/opt/toolchains\)|\1\2|' x    
done
```

I'm not able to understand the function this for loop is doing. Can anyone help.

Comment: Go to `commandlinefu.com` and type `sed -i -e` you'll see various examples which will help you understand the concept better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's iterating over a series of files in the current directory ending with ".la" and for each file found, it's editing the contents using sed to convert lines of the form:

```
libdir=X[zero-or-more-chars]/opt/toolchains
```

(where X is any character) into lines of the form:

```
libdir=X/opt/toolchains.
```

In other words, it's removing the [zero-or-more-chars] part of those lines.

Actually, this looks buggy because I would expect the sed command to reference $x, not x. I have a feeling you lost the $ somehow in the copy/paste step (or perhaps it's simply a bug).

Comment: It means that if "libdir=/var/root/opt/toolchains", it will change to "libdir=//opt/toolchains". Am I right ? Yes, that was the typo. I missed "$".

Comment: It will blindly preserve the character after the equal sign, whatever it is. Assuming it's a leading slash, which is typical, that will be preserved. Probably a better way to explain this is to say that if the text after the equal sign is a pathname, it's removing all of the parent directories above /opt/toolchains.